Prove or give a counterexample of a recursively defined function
Conjecture:
For any given $\alpha\in\mathbb{R},$
Any given bijective continuous function $f:D \rightarrow \mathbb{R_{\ge\alpha}},$
And any given $\mu_\alpha:D\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $D\subset\mathbb{R}$,
Such that$:$
(1) For all $x\in D $, $f(x)\neq\alpha\implies f(x+\mu_\alpha(x))<f(x)$
(2) For all $c\in D$, if $\underset{x\rightarrow c^+}{\lim} \mu_\alpha(x)=0$ or $\underset{x\rightarrow c^-}{\lim} \mu_\alpha(x)=0$, then
$f(c)=\alpha$
Then, it is possible to construct such a function$:$
\begin{equation}
g_{\alpha,\epsilon}(x):=
\begin{cases}
x&\text{ if } f(x)\le\epsilon\\
g_{\alpha,\epsilon}(x+\mu_\alpha (x))&\text{ if }f(x)>\epsilon\\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
$$g_\alpha (x):=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow \alpha^+} g_{\alpha,\epsilon}(x)$$
And we are trying to prove:
$$g_\alpha (x)=f^{-1}(\alpha) $$
That sounds very intuitive. (1) guarantees that the input of $g$ is getting closer and closer to the target, (2) ensures that it won’t stop at somewhere and start looping, bijectivity of $f$ prevents it from oscillating around two points.
However, I have no idea how to prove it. I have come up with some clues, but they don’t seem to be helpful.
Clue 1: Since $f$ is bijective,$$a:=f^{-1}(\alpha )$$
Then, $$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\mu_{\alpha }(x)=0$$
Which can be proved by the inequality
$$\alpha \le f(x+\mu_\alpha(x))<f(x)$$
Take the limit and apply squeeze theorem, make use of the fact that $f$ is bijective and continuous.
Clue 2:
Since $f$ is bijective continuous, $f^{-1}(\alpha )=\max(D)$ or $f^{-1}(\alpha )=\min(D)$
But I don’t know how to continue. Do anyone know how to prove it? Any hints are appreciated!

The set of bijective continuous functions $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R_{\ge \alpha}$ is of very manageable size such that every claim about its elements is true.

@HagenvonEitzen Oh that was a terrible mistake. Thank you for pointing that out!
